# Reactor: Re-write do-while loop to non-blocking way

Tags: java, project-reactor

I am new to reactive programming and trying to re-write this method to non-blocking way.

```java
    // original code
    private Flux<CurrentOrderSummaryDTO> findAllCurrentOrdersInternal(final String appKey, final String sessionToken,
            final ParamsListCurrentOrdersDTO operationParams) {
        boolean hasMoreOrders = true;
        final List<CurrentOrderSummaryDTO> orders = new ArrayList<>();

        do {
            final ParamsListCurrentOrdersDTO nextOperationParams =
                    ParamsListCurrentOrdersDTO.from(operationParams)
                            .fromRecord(orders.size())
                            .build();
            final CurrentOrderSummaryReportDTO nextOrderSummaryReport =
                    listCurrentOrders(appKey, sessionToken, nextOperationParams).block();

            orders.addAll(nextOrderSummaryReport.currentOrders());

            hasMoreOrders = nextOrderSummaryReport.moreAvailable();
        } while (hasMoreOrders);

        return Flux.fromIterable(orders);
    }
```

The problem is that I need the result from the previous call where I get the number of returned items and use them to count the next offset.
One of my approach is to generate the 'fixed-size' page parameters and checking whether there are still some orders to load:

```java
        return Flux
                .generate(() -> buildNextParam(operationParams, 0, MAX_CURRENT_ORDERS_COUNT_PAGE), (state, sink) -> {
                    sink.next(state);
                    return buildNextParam(operationParams, state.fromRecord() + MAX_CURRENT_ORDERS_COUNT_PAGE,
                            MAX_CURRENT_ORDERS_COUNT_PAGE);
                })
                .map(ParamsListCurrentOrdersDTO.class::cast)
                .concatMap(nextParams -> listCurrentOrders(appKey, sessionToken, nextParams))
                .takeUntil(sum -> !sum.moreAvailable())
                .flatMapIterable(CurrentOrderSummaryReportDTO::currentOrders);
```

The problem with this solution is that if the third-party service `listCurrentOrders` returns for what ever reason less items than `MAX_CURRENT_ORDERS_COUNT_PAGE` and also property `moreAvailable == true` then I could miss some items. So I would need to know the returned number of items to correctly build the offset.
Any idea?

### UPDATE

I was able to solve this by introducing an external offset counter.

```
    private Flux<CurrentOrderSummaryDTO> findAllCurrentOrdersInternal(final String appKey, final String sessionToken,
            final ParamsListCurrentOrdersDTO operationParams) {
        return Flux.defer(() -> {
            final AtomicInteger offset = new AtomicInteger();
            return Flux
                    .generate(sink -> sink.next(0))
                    .concatMap(
                            unused -> listCurrentOrders(appKey, sessionToken,
                                    buildNextParam(operationParams, offset.get())))
                    .doOnNext(report -> offset.addAndGet(report.currentOrders()
                            .size()))
                    .takeUntil(report -> !report.moreAvailable())
                    .flatMapIterable(CurrentOrderSummaryReportDTO::currentOrders);
        });
```

But this of course introduced a side-effect code but could not find any better solution.

Comment: Why? What's wrong with what you've got?

Comment: @marquisoflorne do you mean what is wrong with this "side-effect" code? It's shouldn't be "wrong" from result point of view. But introducing a side-effect operation is a bad approach.

Comment: you could wrap the `AtomicInteger`+`Flux` in a `Flux.defer`, at least preventing sharing of state if two subscriptions are made on the same `Flux`